# Javascript Array To Lookup Key Value Pairs

Tags: javascript, json, data-dictionary

I would like to be able to create an object that I could use in conjunction with the following code that could convert keycodes into the appropriate key name.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode === 37) {
    $('#content').html('You pressed the "<strong>Left Arrow</strong>" key');
  } else if (keycode == 39) {
    $('#content').html('You pressed the "<strong>Right Arrow</strong>"     key');
  } else if (keycode == 38) {
    $('#content').html('You pressed the "<strong>Up Arrow</strong>" key');
  } else if (keycode == 40) {
    $('#content').html('You pressed the "<strong>Down Arrow</strong>" key');
  } else {
    $('#content').html('You pressed a key that triggers a(n) <input class="keycode" value="' + event.which + '" /> code');
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/OpErLL

What would a logical way to do something like that entail? KeyValuePair, JSON, Data Dictionary or something else altogether?

Comment: why not just use a normal array since all the keycodes are integers?

Comment: perhaps this library can help you https://github.com/timoxley/keycode you can use it or figure out how they do it and make your own implementation

Answer (score 1):

JSON, Key-value pair, Data dictionaries - all of these are nothing but Javascript objects.

You can declare an object with keys as `keycodes` and values as something you want to use. In the example below, they are strings.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  var keyMap = { 37: 'Left', 38: 'Up', 39: 'Right', 40: 'Down' };
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

  if (keyMap[keycode]) {
    $('#content').html('You pressed the "<strong>' + keyMap[keycode] + ' Arrow</strong>" key');
  } else {
    $('#content').html('You pressed a key that triggers a(n) <input class="keycode" value="' + event.which + '" /> code');
  }
});
```

You can also write functions as values and call them if you want to perform an action.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  var keyMap = {
    37: function () {
      console.log('handle left');
    },
    38: function () {
      console.log('handle up');
    },
    39: function () {
      console.log('handle right');
    },
    40: function () {
      console.log('handle down');
    },
  };

  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

  if (keyMap[keycode]) {
    keyMap[keycode]();
  } else {
    console.log('This key is not handled');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a map called `keyNames` that converts between your `keyCode`s and their name strings (e.g. `'Left Arrow'`). Also note that you can replace your use of the ternary operator (`event.keyCode ? event.keyCode event.which`) with the shorter logical or version (`event.keyCode || event.which`).

```js
var keyNames = {
  37: 'Left Arrow',
  38: 'Up Arrow',
  39: 'Right Arrow',
  40: 'Down Arrow'
}

$(document).keydown(function (event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which
  $('#content').html(keyCode in keyNames ?
    'You pressed the "<strong>' + keyNames[keyCode] + '</strong>" key' :
    'You pressed a key that triggers a(n) <input class="keycode" value="' + keyCode + '" /> code'
  )
})
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px
}

.keycode {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Press a key. Any key.<br /><br />
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to accomplish your goal:

```
var keys = {
   "slash": 191, 
   "up": 38, 
   "down": 40, 
   "left": 37, 
   "right": 39, 
   "enter": 13, 
   "space": 32, 
   "ctrl": 17, 
   "alt": 18, 
   "tab": 9, 
   "esc": 27
};
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
if (keyCode === keys.enter) {
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take the approach of an array of objects with keyCode and keyName values, and use array filter/reduce methods to create the string I want.

```js
const keyLookup = [
    {
        keyCode: 37,
        keyName: 'Left Arrow'
    },
    {
        keyCode: 39,
        keyName: 'Right Arrow'
    }
];

$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    const keyString = keyLookup
    .filter(key => key.keyCode === (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which))
    .reduce((keysPressed, key) => keysPressed += key.keyName, '');
    
    $('#content').html(`You pressed the ${keyString} key.`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code: This code Uses JSON to map key pressed, with its value as key name .

```js
var keyPair = {
  "8": "backspace",
  "9": "tab",
  "13": "enter",
  "16": "shift",
  "17": "ctrl",
  "18": "alt",
  "19": "pause/break",
  "20": "caps lock",
  "27": "esc",
  "32": "space",
  "33": "page up",
  "34": "page down",
  "35": "end",
  "36": "home",
  "37": "left",
  "38": "up",
  "39": "right",
  "40": "down",
  "45": "insert",
  "46": "delete",
  "48": "0",
  "49": "1",
  "50": "2",
  "51": "3",
  "52": "4",
  "53": "5",
  "54": "6",
  "55": "7",
  "56": "8",
  "57": "9",
  "65": "a",
  "66": "b",
  "67": "c",
  "68": "d",
  "69": "e",
  "70": "f",
  "71": "g",
  "72": "h",
  "73": "i",
  "74": "j",
  "75": "k",
  "76": "l",
  "77": "m",
  "78": "n",
  "79": "o",
  "80": "p",
  "81": "q",
  "82": "r",
  "83": "s",
  "84": "t",
  "85": "u",
  "86": "v",
  "87": "w",
  "88": "x",
  "89": "y",
  "90": "z",
  "91": "left command",
  "93": "right command",
  "96": "numpad 0",
  "97": "numpad 1",
  "98": "numpad 2",
  "99": "numpad 3",
  "100": "numpad 4",
  "101": "numpad 5",
  "102": "numpad 6",
  "103": "numpad 7",
  "104": "numpad 8",
  "105": "numpad 9",
  "106": "numpad *",
  "107": "numpad +",
  "109": "numpad -",
  "110": "numpad .",
  "111": "numpad /",
  "112": "f1",
  "113": "f2",
  "114": "f3",
  "115": "f4",
  "116": "f5",
  "117": "f6",
  "118": "f7",
  "119": "f8",
  "120": "f9",
  "121": "f10",
  "122": "f11",
  "123": "f12",
  "144": "num lock",
  "145": "scroll lock",
  "182": "my computer",
  "183": "my calculator",
  "186": ";",
  "187": "=",
  "188": ",",
  "189": "-",
  "190": ".",
  "191": "/",
  "192": "`",
  "219": "[",
  "220": "\\",
  "221": "]",
  "222": "'"
}

$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keyPair.hasOwnProperty(keycode)) {
    $('div').text("You Pressed - " + keyPair[keycode])
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Press any key here : <br/>
<div></div>
```